# Solidity Crowdsale contract tutorial: isn't it possible to call safeWithdrawal AFTER the deadline but before calling checkGoalReached?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

I was reading this tutorial: https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale
The code at the time of writing is this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract token { function transfer(address receiver, uint amount){  } }

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal; uint public amountRaised; uint public deadline; uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    event GoalReached(address beneficiary, uint amountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    /* data structure to hold information about campaign contributors */

    /*  at initialization, setup the owner */
    function Crowdsale(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        token addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /* The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract */
    function () payable {
        if (crowdsaleClosed) throw;
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /* checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign */
    function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    function safeWithdrawal() afterDeadline {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you look at safeWithdrawal it has 2 checks: afterDeadline and !fundingGoalReached for the first block of code within that function.

If I read this correctly, shouldn't it be possible that if the deadline of a crowdsale using this contract is passed, you could call safeWithdrawal() as a participant in the sale, before checkGoalReached is called and get a refund of your funds and still keep the tokens?

The reason why I'm suspecting this is because if checkGoalReached is not called, the fundingGoalReached remains false, and the deadline is passed.

Comment: Looks like it to me, unless something makes arrangements for checkGoalReached always being called when the deadline passes elsewhere. Probably would be better to add another boolean for whether the close decision has been made, and call checkGoalReached() each time when it isn't.